# Did split view controller changed something?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I just add split view from Object library.
After add run that project on iPad Pro simulation.
Why I can't find detail view?
Something changed?

[image]

And so I make it simple after remove some view controller like this.
controll drag and set master, detail.
Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot fully configure a split view controller based on the storyboard alone. Thus, in dragging just the Split View Controller object from the library into the storyboard, you're being handed what amounts to a half-finished piece of work. You have to finish the job yourself — and you clearly don't know how to do that.

The *best* way to make a split view controller setup, in my opinion, is to construct the whole thing in code.

But if you really want Apple to make you a working split view controller setup, then just start by making a new Universal or iPad project based on the Master-Detail template. There, the whole thing is laid out for you, including the necessary code.

Comment: OMG thank you. Key is Universal or iPad project!! thank you!